# calculate average of a column in accordance to another column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have this dummy panda's df:

```
    Feature1    Featrue2
0       X           0
1       X           0
2       Y           0
3       Y           1
4       Y           1
5       X           1
6       Y           0
7       X           1
8       Y           1
9       X           0
```

How do I calculate the average of `Feature2`, only when the value of `Feature1` is X, and the average of `Feature2` again, just when the value of `Feature1` is Y? I figure it's by using `groupby`, however it's not working for me.

My attempt (making a function to find the difference in the two averages):

```
def diff_of_avg(df, column_name , groupby_var):
    groupby_var = df.groupby(groupby_var)
    avgs = groupby_var[column_name].mean()
    return avgs.loc['1'] - avgs.loc['0']
```

where `groupby_var` is `Feature2`

and `column_name` is `Feature1`

Comment: Show your attempt

Comment: What are `'1'` and `'0'` supposed to represent? Maybe you mixed up `.loc['X']` and `.iloc[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
df2 = df.groupby('Feature1').mean()
```

Ouput:

```
          Featrue2
Feature1
X              0.4
Y              0.6
```

Docs for [`mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) give some examples as well.

To find the difference in the averages of `X` and `Y`, you can do this:

```py
diffOfAverages = df.groupby('Feature1').mean().diff().iloc[-1,-1]
```

Output:

```
0.19999999999999996
```